# Error from psycopy2 with UUID-array column type

Tags: postgresql, uuid, psycopg2

I have trouble inserting UUID values into a UUID-array column in Postgres.

Since psycopg2 doesn't automatically convert Python UUID values to Postgres UUID, I use something like `str(my_id)`

However this is the first time I am using any array-type column.  The error I get is:

```
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: column "items" is of type uuid[] but expression is of type text[]
LINE 3: ...0', NULL, '01adae1e-e2cf-11e4-b773-ac8112c8e1fb', ARRAY['01a...
                                                             ^
HINT:  You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
```

I've googled this error and found some (eg [bug 2279](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/pull/2279), [bug 2277](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/pull/2277)) Postgres bug reports that hint at incomplete/missing implementation of array features but I don't know whether these relate to my problem.  These however seem to have been resolved.  FWIW I'm using Postgres 9.3.6

To debug this I created a small test table, eg:

```
testdb=# \d test_table
    Table "public.test_table"
  Column   |  Type   | Modifiers 
-----------+---------+-----------
 key       | integer | 
 item_list | uuid[]  |
```

And the output from my talkative test:

```
DEBUGGING:
Statement:  INSERT INTO test_table
    ("item_list", "key")
    VALUES (%s, %s);
Arguments:  [['2f286cea-e34b-11e4-9b5e-2c768ada7efb', '2f28dd7e-e34b-11e4-9b5e-2c768ada7efb'], 1]
Active Role: test1
Mogrified SQL Expression:
INSERT INTO test_table
    ("item_list", "key")
    VALUES (ARRAY['2f286cea-e34b-11e4-9b5e-2c768ada7efb', '2f28dd7e-e34b-11e4-9b5e-2c768ada7efb'], 1);
Exception ProgrammingError occured. Arguments:
    ('column "item_list" is of type uuid[] but expression is of type text[]\nLINE 3:     VALUES (ARRAY[\'2f286cea-e34b-11e4-9b5e-2c768ada7efb\', \'2...\n                    ^\nHINT:  You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.\n',)
   * * * *   WARNING: Command Failure on Running Statement 
 INSERT INTO test_table
    ("item_list", "key")
    VALUES (%s, %s);!

ERROR:  column "item_list" is of type uuid[] but expression is of type text[]
LINE 3:     VALUES (ARRAY['2f286cea-e34b-11e4-9b5e-2c768ada7efb', '2...
                    ^
HINT:  You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.

None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "db-test.py", line 214, in <module>
    db_exec(cursor, stmt, args, debug=True, re_raise=True)
  File "db-test.py", line 62, in db_exec
    cur.execute(stmt, args)
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: column "item_list" is of type uuid[] but expression is of type text[]
LINE 3:     VALUES (ARRAY['2f286cea-e34b-11e4-9b5e-2c768ada7efb', '2...
                    ^
HINT:  You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
```

The only other thing I've tried is to use uuid raw but I get the expected "Can't adapt" error.

The exception DOES occur one line earlier in my test program, eg

```
DEBUGGING:
Statement:  INSERT INTO test_table
    ("item_list", "key")
    VALUES (%s, %s);
Arguments:  [[UUID('2bfaf276-e34c-11e4-8af5-2c768ada7efb'), UUID('2bfb6d82-e34c-11e4-8af5-2c768ada7efb')], 1]
Active Role: test1
Mogrified SQL Expression:
Exception ProgrammingError occured. Arguments:
    ("can't adapt type 'UUID'",)
   * * * *   WARNING: Command Failure on Running Statement 
 INSERT INTO test_table
    ("item_list", "key")
    VALUES (%s, %s);!

None
None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "db-test.py", line 214, in <module>
    db_exec(cursor, stmt, args, debug=True, re_raise=True)
  File "db-test.py", line 61, in db_exec
    print cur.mogrify(stmt, args)
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: can't adapt type 'UUID'
```

The relevant part of the test program looks like this:

```
46  def db_exec(cur, stmt, args=None, re_raise=True, debug=False, assume_role=None):
47      if (cur is None) or (cur is False):
48          print "ERROR : DB Connection/Cursor is not open for commands"
49          return cur
50      if (debug is True):
51          print "DEBUGGING:"
52          print "Statement: ", stmt
53          if args is not None:
54              print "Arguments: ", args
55      try:
56          if assume_role is not None:
57              cur.execute('SET ROLE "%s";' % assume_role)
58          if debug is True:
59              print "Active Role:", GetCurrentRole(cur)
60              print "Mogrified SQL Expression:"
61              print cur.mogrify(stmt, args)
62          cur.execute(stmt, args)
[...snip...]
```

I have seen that there exists a way to add custom "autmatic" type conversions for Python <--> Postgres and wonder whether the solution may lie in there... but I don't know how to do that (yet)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I decided to investigate the psycopg2 extras and found a solution that involves just one extra line of code.

The hint came from [here](https://pythonhosted.org/psycopg2/_sources/extras.txt), found near the bottom of that page in the section under the heading "UUID data type"

The line is:

```
psycopg2.extras.register_uuid()
```

Despite my pesimism about this work for both simple AND array UUID types, it does so just fine.  In addition this means I no longer need to manually convert every UUID to a str.  (The reverse is not an issue in my application but presumably it would also work for retrieving UUIDs and having them registered as UUID type in python)